# Escape character for replacement character in unix

Tags: unix, sed, escaping

What's the escape character for `&` (to include the match in the replacement)?

I need to replace `cat` in file with `&quo;cat&quo;`

```
cat file | sed -e 's\cat\&quo;cat&quo;\'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is not an optimal choice for the substitution delimiter – `/` is often used, and much better suited in this case because `\` is used for escaping:

```
sed 's/cat/\&quo;cat\&quo;/' file
```

Notice that you don't have to use `cat` to pipe to sed; just give the input file as an argument.

`&` has to be escaped to get a literal `&`; otherwise, it stands for the whole matched portion of the pattern space (see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)):

```
$ sed 's/XXX/~&~/' <<< 'aaaXXXaaa'
aaa~XXX~aaa
$ sed 's/XXX/~\&~/' <<< 'aaaXXXaaa'
aaa~&~aaa
```

Comment: you might want to explain why the `&` char requires escaping.

Comment: @glennjackman Ah, yes, I'll do that. OP was aware that there's something special about it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Characters that need escaping are different in Bourne or POSIX shell than Bash. Generally (very) Bash is a superset of those shells, so anything you escape in `shell` should be escaped in Bash.

A nice general rule would be "if in doubt, escape it". But escaping some characters gives them a special meaning, like `\n`. These are listed in the `man bash` pages under `Quoting` and `echo`.

Other than that, escape any character that is not alphanumeric, it is safer. I don't know of a single definitive list.

The man pages list them all somewhere, but not in one place. Learn the language, that is the way to be sure.

One that has caught me out is `!`. This is a special character (history expansion) in Bash (and csh) but not in Korn shell. Even `echo "Hello world!"` gives problems. Using single-quotes, as usual, removes the special meaning.